# Not able to install fluxgui on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install flux on ubuntu 15.10 using these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kilian/f.lux 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install fluxgui
```

But I am getting following error messages

```
W: Failed to fetch 

http://ppa.launchpad.net/fantasyleague0629/wildguppy/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fantasyleague0629/wildguppy/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What should I do now?

Comment: I answered your question. Please reply and please tell me if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kilian’s repository for flux does not update anymore. But you can install it as given below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nathan-renniewaldock/flux
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fluxgui
```

**NOTE :** you might need to remove kilan's ppa before doing the above steps, to do that :

Remove the old repository :

```
 sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:kilian/f.lux
```

Remove [its gpg keys](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/17084265/):

```
sudo apt-key del 9BD4ED25
```

Update sources.list

```
sudo apt-get update
```